# Android user login system using SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

I'm attempting to implement a simple login system in my android application, but I'm a bit stuck with a runtime exception that I can't work out. I'm pretty new to Android, in fact this will be my first app. I've tried going through with the debugger but I get a lot of 'attach source', not sure what I should do with that? Either way, I can't seem to work out what is throwing the exception from the debugger, but the error is a NullPointerException in my AttemptLogin method at the line where it attempts to getUserByName. I've checked the userName that is passed across and that seems fine, not sure what else I need to check!? Have I made some sort of newbie error that I just can't spot?

```
package com.devTB.styleboutique_clientmanagement;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UserLogin extends Activity {

    private SQLiteAdapter sqLiteAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AttemptLogin();
            }
        });
    }


    public void AttemptLogin()
    {
        TextView txtUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
        TextView txtPass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
        String userName = txtUser.getText().toString();
        String inputPassword = txtPass.getText().toString();

        Cursor c = sqLiteAdapter.getUserByName(userName);
        if(c.getCount() == 0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User name does not exist",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            txtUser.setText("");
            txtPass.setText("");
            return;
        }

        // decrypt password from database
        String password = PwCrypt.decryptPassword(c.getBlob(2));

        if(inputPassword == password)
        {
            User.setId(c.getInt(0));
            User.setUserName(userName);
            User.setUserAdmin(true);
            // Login
            Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect password",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            txtPass.setText("");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

SQLiteAdapter method:

```
public Cursor getUserByName(String userName)
{
    String[] columns = new String[]{ COL_USERS_ID,
                                     COL_USERS_NAME,
                                     COL_USERS_PW,
                                     COL_USERS_ADMIN };

    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYTABLE_USERS, columns, COL_USERS_NAME + " = '" + userName + "'", null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your logcat output?

Comment: Please oh please *include the exception and stacktrace* when you have an exception :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your on create method, you need to initialize your sqLiteAdapter (mSQLiteAdapter is a more proper name) . It will be something like:`sqLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);`

If you don't initialize it, you are just calling a null object which throws an exception even though it is defined as that object.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

As you mention, the error is in this line:

```
Cursor c = sqLiteAdapter.getUserByName(userName);
```

You get a `NullPointerException`, which means that somewhere on that line, some object is null (and you try to call a method on it), which is impossible. The only possibility here is that sqLiteAdapter is null, which makes sense, because you never create it.

What you need to do is create the sqLiteAdapter in your `onCreate()` method.